# jQuery .abort() on keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that this question is asked in many ways, I'm also able to make it work. It only doesn't work in combination with a key* event...
Why doesn't `.abort()` work in this function?

```
function setGlobalSearch(){
    var xhr;
    $('#globalSearch').keyup(function(){
        if(xhr && xhr.readystate != 4){
            xhr.abort();
        }
        var searchVal = $(this).val();
        xhr = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/ajax.actions?i=globalSearch&q="+searchVal,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#globalSearchResults').html(data);
            },
            dataType:"html",
            cache:false
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `abort()` function will only fire if the request has been sent. I can only suggest that this is possibly not the case.

However, I would recommend a different pattern which negates the need to abort requests, which is, as you've seen, occasionally a little flaky. Instead I would only fire the request once typing has ceased for a set number of milliseconds. Try this:

```
var timer;
$('#globalSearch').keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        var searchVal = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/ajax.actions?i=globalSearch&q="+searchVal,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#globalSearchResults').html(data);
            },
            dataType:"html",
            cache:false
        });
    }, 150); // fire the AJAX request 150ms after typing stops.
});
```